# Change UIBarButtonItem Text Font Size and Color

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to know how can I change the text font of the `BarButtonItem` ? While I could not set the setTitleTextAttributes

```
class TextfieldLogin : UITextField {

func INIT(){
    let numberToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,50))
    numberToolbar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    numberToolbar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 155.0/255, green: 14.0/255, blue: 45.0/255, alpha: 1.0)

    numberToolbar.items = [
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "DONE", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "close"),
        UIBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor(),NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()],
            forState: UIControlState.Normal)        ]

    numberToolbar.sizeToFit()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Is this what your looking for?

Objective-C:

```
[buttonItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0], NSFontAttributeName,
[UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Swift:

```
let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName: "Helvetica-Bold"]
self.numberToolbar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict
```

Comment: can you customize your answer to swift , the questioner need the answer in swift

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.Karthik . Yes please I need the answer in Swift.

Comment: updated my answer to include Swift, I don't use Swift much so sorry if you need to change it up a little.  You get the concept of setting those NavBar TitleTextAttributes though right?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog I can't call navigationController in the  UITextField class. Please check

Comment: Update my answer: how about that, will that work for you?

Comment: Wonderful.  Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you are changing this on the main thread or it will not update.

Answer (score 3):

As with all `UIBarItem`'s, you can set the text attributes using:

```
- (void)setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
                      forState:(UIControlState)state
```

You can also use `tintColor` to change the text color.

I would recommend sticking to Apple's style guide in terms of using bold fonts only on the `done` item.